# Boolean variable not checking

Tags: apex, class

I'm trying to write a scheduled class that ticks a check box if it's unchecked, and if it's checked it un ticks the box. What is it that I'm doing wrong with my code? Thanks in advance, I am a complete moron at coding!

```
global class birthdayScheduledApex implements Schedulable {
    global void execute (schedulableContext SC) {
        if (Send_Birthday_Email__c = False) {
            Send_Birthday_Email__c = 'True';
        } else if (Send_Birthday_Email__c = True) {
            Send_Birthday_Email__c = 'False';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're setting it to false instead of checking to see if it's false. Use '==' instead of '=' in your if statements. I.e. if(Send_Birthday_Email__c == False){}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are trying to create simple Semaphore.

- For the first you should select records, which you wants to update.
- In for loop make update.
- Save Records.

Let's assume that you have field Send_Birthday_Email__c on contact object, then simple Schedulable class could look like:

```
global class birthdayScheduledApex implements Schedulable {
    global void execute (schedulableContext SC) {

        list<contact> contacts = [select name, Send_Birthday_Email__c from contact];

        for (contact con :contacts) {
            con.Send_Birthday_Email__c = !con.Send_Birthday_Email__c;
        }

        update contacts;
    }
}
```

You can test within console:

```
birthdayScheduledApex b= new birthdayScheduledApex();
String cronStr = '0 10 * * * ?';
System.schedule('Process Accs Job', cronStr, b);
```

Where `0 10 * * * ?` presents every ten minutes in hour.

Comment: Upvoted. However, it is best practice for readability to add curly braces regardless of whether the content of the loop is a one-liner or not. I would amend my sample to provide the OP with a better answer.

Comment: @GlennDaly (1) N.B. if > 10000 Contacts selected, OP will blow up dml limits; this should be a scheduled batchable or some other way of limiting updates; (2) globals not required unless managed package; `public` suffices

Comment: Thanks very much for your help all, note to self, don't try coding after a couple of beers!